# I am generating a PDF file using wkhtmltopdf in python, but the images overlap

Tags: python, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJcTa.png)

I am generating a PDF file using wkhtmltopdf in python, but the images overlap.

As in the attached screenshot, the images overlap, so I tried to find all the manuals and stackoverflow methods provided by wkhtmltopdf, but could not solve the overlapping phenomenon.

I hope you can tell me a good solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

must it be Python?
can you have a look to (pdf) LaTeX ?
With LaTeX, you can easily create all type of documentation for producing pdf
files, books, articles, ...

Comment: It is already made with wkhtmltopdf in Python.
In the case of the Latex you recommended, I don't think it's a good opinion because there's a lot of scope to work on.
Please reply only to the wkhtmltopdf you are currently working on.